# Replicação de dados simples no PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, replicação

Criei duas tabelas com chave primária e precisava replicá-las,ou seja colocá-las em outro *database* mas tudo na mesma máquina. Como deveria fazer isso?

As tabelas criadas são essas:

```
CREATE TABLE cities1 (
        city     varchar(80) primary key,
        location point
);

CREATE TABLE weather10 (
        city      varchar(80) references cities1(city),
        temp_lo   int,
        temp_hi   int,
        prcp      real,
        date      date
) 


INSERT INTO weather VALUES ('San Francisco', 46, 50, 0.25, '1994-11-27');//insere uma linha na tabela com os dados

INSERT INTO cities VALUES ('San Francisco', '(-194.0, 53.0)');
```

Comment: Qual o tipo de replicação desejada? Master-master, master-slave, síncrona, assíncrona?

Comment: Então, gostaria de simplesmente replicar essas tabelas que criei para outro banco, tudo na mesma máquina.

Comment: Existem vários tipos de replicação. Cada uma delas te permite acessar os dados de uma forma. Sem saber qual o modo como você deseja usar os dados, não há como indicar a replicação mais apropriada. Portanto, vou indicar a documentação do PostgreSQL sobre replicação: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/high-availability.html

Answer (score 2):

Pelo que eu entendi, o seu conceito de replicação é o de cópia simples, de um database para outro.
Neste caso, a forma mais simples é você usar o comando "pg_dump", se você estiver somente com essas 2 tabelas e quer copiá-las para outro database basta fazer:

```
pg_dump seu_database > arquivo
```

Depois é só você dar um restore para seu novo banco, abra o terminal e use o comando psql da seguinte forma

```
psql outro_database < arquivo
```

Você também pode fazer a exportação e importação de uma vez só:

```
pg_dump -h host1 database_origem | psql -h host2 database_destino
```

Agora se você estiver usando o PGAdmin, fica mais fácil ainda, é só você clicar com o botão direito do mouse na tabela e escolher "backup"
Depois você vai até o database destino e clica em restore e coloca o arquivo que você acabou de salvar, assim essa tabela será incorporada no database destino.

Referências: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/backup-dump.html